# Некорректно работает поиск элемента в списке

Tags: python

Не могу понять, почему код работает некорректно.
Такой код работает как надо - находит самый большой элемент в списке. Итоговое `max_` = 33:

```
teststring = [1,2,33,4,5,6]
max_ = teststring[0]
for i in teststring:
    print(f'Сейчас max_ = {max_}\nСейчас i = {i}\n')
        if i > max_:
            max_ = i
            print(f'i > max_, значит теперь max_ = {max_}\n')
        
print(f'max_ получился = {max_}')
```

Такой же код, но работает уже некорректно. Итоговое `max_` = 45:

```
prob = ("15 241 33 1234 45")
teststring = prob.split()
max_ = teststring[0]
for i in teststring:
    print(f'Сейчас max_ = {max_}\nСейчас i = {i}\n')
    if i > max_:
        max_ = i
        print(f'i > max_, значит теперь max_ = {max_}\n')

print(f'max_ получился = {max_}')
```

Comment: Потому что во втором случае вы сравниваете не цифры а строки. ‘45’ «больше» других.

Comment: Проще всего "починить" так: `if int(i) > int(max_)`, но если там не только целые числа бывают, то всё несколько сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

На ваш вопрос уже есть ответ в интернете: https://question-it.com/questions/1875909/tehnika-sravnenija-strok-ispolzuemaja-python
Цитата:

> При сравнении используется лексикографический порядок: сначала сравниваются первые два элемента, и если они различаются, это определяет результат сравнения; если они равны, сравниваются следующие два элемента и так далее, пока не будет исчерпана любая последовательность.

Также:

> Лексикографическое упорядочение строк использует номер кодовой точки Unicode для упорядочения отдельных символов.